If $F$ is an algebraic number field such that $e^{2\pi i/n} \in F$ for some $n\geq 3$, then the norm of any nonzero element of $F$ is positive

Prove that if $F$ is an algebraic number field such that $e^{2\pi i/n}\in F$ for some $n\geq 3$, then the norm of any nonzero element of $F$ is positive.

This is from Exercise 13.3 of Rosen and Ireland's A Classical Introduction To Modern Number Theory. I've seen the proof in here, but the OP likely used the knowledge that I didn't have. My attempt is finding a subfield $L$ between $F$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ with $N_{L/\mathbb{Q}}$ is always positive, then using the tower property for norms: $N_{F/\mathbb{Q}}(x)=N_{L/\mathbb{Q}}(N_{F/L}(x))$. However, I couldn’t identify such an $L$. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!


Have you tried using $L=\Bbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/n})$? 2) Do you know that if $L/K$ is Galois, then the norm of an element is a product of its automorphic images?



Yes, but I don't know how to prove the norm is positive. 2) Yes



If $z\in L=\Bbb{Q}(e^{2\pi /n})$ why do the automorphic images of $z$ come in complex conjugate pairs?


The automorphism in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n})/\mathbb{Q}$ looks like $\sigma:\zeta_{n}\mapsto \zeta_{n}^{i}$ where $(i,n)=1$. Then for each $i$, $(n-i,n)=1$, so there exists automorphism $\tau:\zeta_{n}\mapsto \zeta_{n}^{n-i}$. Since $\sigma(\zeta_{n})=\bar{\tau(\zeta_{n})}$ and they're homomophisms, $\sigma(z)=\bar{\tau(z)}$ for all $z\in\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n})$. If $n$ is odd, $n-i\neq i$ for all $i$, thus $\sigma(z),\tau(z)\in\mathbb{C}$ are conjugate pairs. If $n=2k$, then $\sigma=\tau$ when $i=k$, but $(k,2k)\neq 1$ when $n>2$, thus again $\sigma(z),\tau(z)\in\mathbb{C}$ are conjugate pairs.

Therefore, we can pair the automorphic images of $z$, using $z\bar{z}=|z|>0$, then get a positive norm.

Correct. That's the way I think the hint in the related thread goes. You are welcome to post it as an answer (here or there). Then we can close one as a duplicate of the other.

Thank you very much!

By the tower property of norms, it suffices to prove $N_{L/\mathbb{Q}}$ is a positive norm when $L=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n})$.
Since the norm is the product of its automorphic images, we claim that the automorphic images can be paired into complex conjugates. Using $z\bar{z}=|z|^2>0$, the norm becomes the product of the form $|z|^2$, hence is positive.
Note that the automorphism in $L/\mathbb{Q}$ always looks like $\sigma:\zeta_{n}\mapsto\zeta_{n}^{i}$ where $(i,n)=1$. Then for each $i$, $(n−i,n)=1$, so there exists automorphism $\tau:\zeta_{n}\mapsto\zeta_{n}^{n-i}.$ Since $\sigma(\zeta_{n})=\overline{\tau(\zeta_{n})}$ and they're homomorphism,  $\sigma(z)=\overline{\tau(z)}$ for all $z\in L$.
If $n$ is odd, $n-i\neq i$ for all $i$, thus $\sigma(z),\tau(z)\in\mathbb{C}$ are conjugate pairs.
If $n=2k$, then $\sigma=\tau$ when $i=k$, but $(k,2k)\neq 1$ when $n>2$, thus again $\sigma(z),\tau(z)\in\mathbb{C}$ are conjugate pairs.

Good job. The upvote is mine. I will be deleting the comments shortly.
